# What do some of the fields returned from ActiveMQ.Agent query mean?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm trying to do some kind of administration on our activemq process, and I'd like to know what some of the fields mean that I get back.

Specifically,

What is InFlightCount? Is that the number of messages that the producer has sent but not 
What is AverageEnqueueTime measured in? Seconds?
What are EnqueueCount and DequeueCount?
What is DispatchCount?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Quoting from [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@activemq.apache.org/msg08847.html):

**InFlightCount**: The number of messages that have been dispatched and are
currently awaiting acknowledgment from the consumer.  So as this number
decreases, the DequeueCount increases.

**AverageEnqueueTime**: On average, the amount of time (ms) that messages
remained enqueued. Or average time it is taking the consumers to
successfully process messages.

**EnqueueCount**: The number of messages that have been written to the queue
over the lifetime of the queue.

**DequeueCount**: The number of messages that have been successfully (i.e.,
they’ve been acknowledged from the consumer) read off the queue over the
lifetime of the queue.

**DispatchCount**: The number of messages that have been dispatched (sent) to
the consumer over the lifetime of the queue. Note that dispatched messages
may not have all been acknowledged.

Comment: Candiru, can you tell us  if you know the source of this information? Or is it only on the email?

Answer (score 0):

Some points are not matching my observation. One thing is dequeue count; I noticed that

```
dequeue = expired + dispatched
```

So dequeue = removed from queue by any reason(expired or dispatched); it does not necessarily mean acked; it's just "number of messages removed from the queue by any reason"; if expired, there's should not be ack, ofc.

Even [doc of ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-find-the-size-of-a-queue) does not match what I saw.